# How can I fix these broken synonyms?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, synonyms

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT S.OWNER   AS SYN_OWNER,
  S.SYNONYM_NAME AS SYN_NAME,
  S.TABLE_OWNER  AS OBJ_OWNER,
  S.TABLE_NAME   AS OBJ_NAME,
  CASE
    WHEN O.OWNER IS NULL
    THEN 'MISSING'
    ELSE O.STATUS
  END AS OBJ_STATUS
FROM DBA_SYNONYMS S
LEFT JOIN DBA_OBJECTS O
ON S.TABLE_OWNER = O.OWNER
AND S.TABLE_NAME = O.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE O.OWNER   IS NULL
OR O.STATUS     != 'VALID';
```

It gives me the following output:

```
PUBLIC  GV$LOADPSTAT    SYSTEM  GV_$LOADPSTAT   INVALID
PUBLIC  GV$LOADISTAT    SYSTEM  GV_$LOADISTAT   INVALID
PUBLIC  V$LOADPSTAT SYSTEM  V_$LOADPSTAT    INVALID
PUBLIC  V$LOADISTAT SYSTEM  V_$LOADISTAT    INVALID
PUBLIC  LOADER_CONSTRAINT_INFO  SYSTEM  LOADER_CONSTRAINT_INFO  MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_COL_INFO SYSTEM  LOADER_COL_INFO MISSING
PUBLIC  GV$DB_TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM    SYS GV$_DB_TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM   MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_COL_TYPE SYSTEM  LOADER_COL_TYPE MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_OID_INFO SYSTEM  LOADER_OID_INFO MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_PARAM_INFO   SYSTEM  LOADER_PARAM_INFO   MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_FULL_ATTR_NAME   SYSTEM  LOADER_FULL_ATTR_NAME   MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_INTCOL_INFO  SYSTEM  LOADER_INTCOL_INFO  MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_NESTED_VARRAYS   SYSTEM  LOADER_NESTED_VARRAYS   MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_LOB_FLAGS    SYSTEM  LOADER_LOB_FLAGS    MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_DIR_OBJS SYSTEM  LOADER_DIR_OBJS MISSING
PUBLIC  GV$SYSTEM_FIX_CONTROL   SYS GV$SYSTEM_FIX_CONTROL   MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_PART_INFO    SYSTEM  LOADER_PART_INFO    MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_COL_FLAGS    SYSTEM  LOADER_COL_FLAGS    MISSING
SYS DEF$_SCHEDULE   SYSTEM  DEF$_SCHEDULE   MISSING
PUBLIC  GV$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM   SYS GV$_TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM  MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_TRIGGER_INFO SYSTEM  LOADER_TRIGGER_INFO MISSING
PUBLIC  LOADER_TAB_INFO SYSTEM  LOADER_TAB_INFO MISSING
```

If I try to recompile or drop these:

```
ALTER PUBLIC SYNONYM GV_$LOADPSTAT COMPILE;
```

It says:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
```

**How could this be so? I'm logged in as SYSTEM.**

If I try to drop it:

```
DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM GV_$LOADPSTAT;
```

It says:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01432: public synonym to be dropped does not exist
01432. 00000 -  "public synonym to be dropped does not exist"
```

**How can it not exist when the query result shows it?**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, DBA_SYNONYMS.SYNONYM_NAME is the name of the synonym.
DBA_SYNONYMS.TABLE_NAME is the name of the object the synonym points to.
In your query, it is not the synonym that is `INVALID`, but the object that it points to.
It is not the synonym that needs to be fixed, but the object.

> If I try to recompile or drop these:
>
> `ALTER PUBLIC SYNONYM GV_$LOADPSTAT COMPILE;`
>
> It says:
>
> `SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`
>
> `01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"`
>
> **How could this be so? I'm logged in as SYSTEM.**

It is a bug on your version.

> If I try to drop it:
>
> `DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM GV_$LOADPSTAT; It says:`
>
> `SQL Error: ORA-01432: public synonym to be dropped does not exist`
>
> `01432. 00000 -  "public synonym to be dropped does not exist"`
>
> **How can it not exist when the query result shows it?**

Then name of the synonym is `GV$LOADPSTAT`. You are trying to drop the object (view) here, called: `GV_$LOADPSTAT`. And that view is owned by SYS, not SYSTEM.

Where you see `MISSING`, the synonyms points to a non-existent object. Replace the object or drop the synonym.